# Is it bad practice to start a uiview outside of the screen?

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I have a UIView, which I want to show when a button is pressed, right now I am trying to initialize it to be outside of the screen in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`,  when the button is pressed it will slide into the screen, is it bad practice to have that? Is there another way to animate this kind of sliding without having the frame outside of the screen?

Comment: That's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no harm in doing it your way. Another approach might be this:

- Create your view and make it hidden.
- Add it as subview and place it where you want it to land after animation is finished.
- Then apply a transform on it:

  `aView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(dx, dy);`

  Say you want to move it outside of the screen horizontally. So dx would be something like 400 points. I would suggest calculating it based on `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width` to be compatible with every screen.
- On next step make view visible again and apply identity transform inside animation block:

  ```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
          aView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
      }];
  ```

  It will magically slide to it's place.